# Inserting a date into a database does not work (ASPX/C#)

Tags: c#, sql, database, date

I have this C# code:

```
string RegisterDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
RegisterDate = RegisterDate.Remove(10);
RegisterDate = RegisterDate.Replace('/', '-');
RegisterDate = String.Join("-", RegisterDate.Split('-').Reverse());
```

Which gives thie result: **01-06-2013**

The problem is that when I try to insert it to the table I get this result: **21/06/1894**

When I get the date via input it works great in the same date format, so why in this case it doesn't work?

**update**

If I try this:

```
    var RegisterDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
```

I get Error :

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Wish for help, thanks!

Comment: What is your datatype in the DB? DateTime?

Comment: Yes in DD/MM/YYYY format

Comment: Any reason why you cant use the DateTime object in your application instead of a string?

Comment: @NaveTseva: If it's a `DateTime` in the database, it doesn't *have* an inherent format. Just because it happens to be shown in `dd/MM/yyyy` format when you convert results to text doesn't mean that format is in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
string RegisterDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy");
```

and then store in database.

There is no need to manually convert date to different representation. You can go through this [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). But, I agree on Jon Skeet's comment below this answer:

> If you want to represent a date/time type, use a date/time type. That
>   way you're able to take advantage of all kinds of things that the
>   database can do with date/time values, and  you'll never get any
>   non-date/time values in that field.

**Note:**

`DateTime` type uses the `Gregorian calendar` as their default calendar. So, as pointed out by Jon Skeet, this answer won't work with other calenders(Non-Gregorian calendars).

Comment: It's a really bad idea to go through a string conversion at all, IMO. Note that if you're using a culture which has a non-Gregorian calendar system, this will do seriously odd things to the values, too.

Comment: But your code still converts the date to a string representation, despite you saying "There is no need to manually convert date to different representation" - you *are* converting it to a "different" representation by using `ToString`. Why do that? Why not just keep it as a `DateTime`?

Comment: @JonSkeet That line was for `RegisterDate = RegisterDate.Remove(10);
RegisterDate = RegisterDate.Replace('/', '-');
RegisterDate = String.Join("-", RegisterDate.Split('-').Reverse());` that OP was using for manually converting DateTime to his required format.

Comment: I think you've missed my point. A `DateTime` value is the closest direct equivalent to a `DateTime` value in the database - so even in your code, you're changing representation, for no reason. It's a really bad idea to do so, as it causes all kinds of problems. The OP should avoid performing the string conversion *at all*. See my answer for a better (IMO) approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet If we convert `DateTime` to string and then add that string to database. Then what can be the potential problems in it if we are not using `DateTime` type of field in database for that?

Comment: If you're not using a `DateTime` field in the database to start with, then the schema is broken IMO. Semantics are important: if you want to represent a date/time type, *use* a date/time type. That way you're able to take advantage of all kinds of things that the database can do with date/time values, and you know you'll never get any non-date/time values. Why would you *want* to use a textual type to store a date/time? Note that using your proposed format, the values won't even be *sorted* naturally.

Comment: @JonSkeet So storing `DateTime` in database is always a best practise against storing it with different data-type or format. Thankx for the sorting thing, I haven't ever thought about it.

Comment: This isn't just about `DateTime`. If you're storing a number in a database, store it in a numeric type. If you're storing binary data, store that in a binary data type. You wouldn't use a `string` variable to store a logical `int` in C# code, so why do it in a database? The data type you choose for your field should match the data you store in it as closely as possible, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks Jon, you taught me very important things today.I agree on your point. I have added some of your points in answer. Please edit my answer, if you want to add more points..:P

Comment: Fortunately (based on the question comments) I think the OP is already using a `DateTime` type in the database - I'm worried he may be constructing SQL via string manipulation though, making other code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Unfortunately he appears to have taken this answer and run, so to speak. Hopefully he'll come back and see the paramerized approach too...

Comment: @JonSkeet From question, it is not clear, if he is going to use string manipulation and I hope he is using parameterized approach.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a string conversion at all. Assuming your data type in the database is `DateTime` or something similar, just use a parameter and specify its value as the `DateTime` in your C# code to start with. (I'm assuming you're already using parameterized SQL rather than embedding data straight in your SQL. If you're not using parameters yet, start right away!)

I'd suggest using `DateTime.Today` to make it clearer that you're only interested in the date part. (Note that this means that the same code running in different places could end up inserting different dates - is that okay? Normally I don't like letting the system local time zone affect things.)

You should generally avoid string conversions unless you really *need* a string representation of the data. At other times they just cause trouble.

EDIT: You asked for an example. It would be something like:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Foo (Name, RegisterDate) VALUES (@Name, @RegisterDate)",
        connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
                          .Value = name;
        // TODO: Consider whether you really want the *local* date, or some
        // fixed time zone such as UTC
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RegisterDate", SqlDbType.DateTime))
                          .Value = DateTime.Today;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But can you post how the code should look like? (I just leaning this and I have no experiance in C# so much yet)

Comment: @NaveTseva: See my edit. You should *always* use parameters for values in SQL - if you're currently just building a SQL string including the values inside it, your code may well be at risk of SQL injection attacks.